# Trouble with do-while() ending

Tags: c#

I'm having a little problem with this code below.

I marked the problem in the code also.

Its a simple craps game without the feature of balance or winning anything,
it works fine, except it won't stop when `nyStig == 7`, in the long 
 if statement ,`(if (stig == 4||stig == 5||stig == 6||stig == 8||stig == 9||stig == 10))`, I know that I should just edit the ending of the do loop, `(while(nyStig != stig || nyStig != 7))`, but if I do that then nothing works.

```
//CRAPS

Random teningur1 = new Random ();
Random teningur2 = new Random ();

nyStig = ten3 + ten4;
ten3 = teningur1.Next(1,7);
ten4 = teningur2.Next(1,7);

ten1 = teningur1.Next(1,7);
ten2 = teningur2.Next(1,7);

stig = ten1 + ten2;

if (stig == 7 || stig == 11)
{
    //Print stuff to console
}

if (stig == 2 || stig == 3 || stig == 12)
{
    //Print stuff to console
}

if (stig == 4||stig == 5||stig == 6||stig == 8||stig == 9||stig == 10)
{
    do //the problem
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Ýttu á enter til að kasta");
        Console.ReadLine();

        ten3 = teningur1.Next(1,7);
        ten4 = teningur1.Next(1,7);

        //Print stuff to console

        nyStig = ten3 + ten4;

        //Print stuff to console

        if (nyStig == stig)
        {
            //Print stuff to console
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (nyStig != 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Kemur .. kastaðu aftur ");
        }
        if (nyStig == 7)
        {
            //Print stuff to console
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }while(stig != nyStig); //if I add || nyStig != 7) it won't stop.
```

Comment: Hard to tell from the description, but it sounds like you want `while(stig != nyStig && nyStig != 7)`.

Comment: If `stig` is not equal to 7, then `nyStig` will be different from at least one of them. Take an example. If `stig` happen to end up as 5, `nyStig` will either be different from 7 or different from 5, it cannot possible be equal to both (which will terminate the loop) at the same time. You sure you don't want `&&` instead of `||` ? You need to explain in english why you want the loop to terminate, until then all we can comment is your code which is quite unclear.

Comment: haha that was it, I've been putting || instead of && - thanks for that :) @GlorinOakenfoot

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes sorry, this is in Icelandic and I thought the problem would be so clear to someone who has not been looking at this for hours, so I didn't translate it.

Comment: You don't need two `Random` number generators. One static instance would work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop should be do while (dice-throw != 7 && dice-throw != point number)